# Using another partial to render a collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial-views

My cart model contain line_items. I am working in a cart view.

In a view if i do :

```
<%= render cart.line_items%>
```

The _line_item.html.erb partial is rendered. To use another partial, it need a more verbose syntax of render. Before trying to use another partial I want to call my current partial like this :

```
<%= render :partials => "line_items/_line_item", :collection => cart.line_items %>
```

It does not work, here is the error :

> undefined method `formats' for nil:NilClass

I have tried with and without underscore and a few other syntax. What is wrong in this partial call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the partial with:

```
<%= render :partial => "line_items/line_item", :collection => cart.line_items %>
```

if you partial is called _line_item.html.erb in line_items folder.